# FabricJS can't scale image after using setSrc

Tags: canvas, fabricjs

I am using the fabricJS setSrc function to replace images on the canvas after editing. I need to maintain the width of the original image after replacing it, but it doesn't seem to work how I think it should. Here is my function:

```
function replace_current_img(src){
    if(selected_object){
         //Get current object width
         var current_width=selected_object.getWidth();

         selected_object.setSrc(src, function(){
              selected_object.scaleToWidth(current_width);
              canvas.renderAll();
         });
     }
 }
```

I have verified that the **current_width** variable is being set properly, however nothing seems to make the replaced image resize after loading. Another oddity is that I can enter this exact code (with a manually set current_width) in the console and it works as expected.

I have even tried using setTimeout to void any loading issues, but that doesn't work either.

Is there a special way to set the width of an image object after using setSrc?

Answer (score 1):

This could be accomplished either one of the following two ways ...

**▸** **adding**

```
selected_object.scaleToHeight(current_height);
```

followed by the line

```
selected_object.scaleToWidth(current_width);
```

**▸** **using** [**`setWidth`**](http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.StaticCanvas.html#setWidth) and [**`setHeight`**](http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.StaticCanvas.html#setHeight) method

```
selected_object.setWidth(current_width);
selected_object.setHeight(current_height);
```

**ᴅᴇᴍᴏ**

```js
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvas')
var replace_img = document.querySelector('#replace_img');

fabric.Image.fromURL('http://lorempixel.com/100/100/', function (img) {
    img.set({
        top: 40,
        left: 40
    })
    canvas.add(img);
});

function replace_current_img(src) {
    selected_object = canvas.getActiveObject();
    if (selected_object) {
        //Get current object width
        var current_width = selected_object.getWidth();
        var current_height = selected_object.getHeight();
        selected_object.setSrc(src, function () {
            // method#1
            selected_object.scaleToWidth(current_width);
            selected_object.scaleToHeight(current_height);
            // method#2
            // selected_object.setWidth(current_width);
            // selected_object.setHeight(current_height);
            canvas.renderAll();
        });
    }
}

replace_img.onclick = function () {
    replace_current_img('http://lorempixel.com/100/100/');
}
```

```css
canvas{border: 1px solid #ccc}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/1.7.11/fabric.min.js"></script>
<button id="replace_img">Replace Image</button>
<canvas id="canvas" width="180" height="180"></canvas>
```

Comment: Appreciate the feedback, however this solutions doesn't work. Try replacing the image with an image of a different size than the original and you will see the issue. The scaleToWidth() doesn't work in the callback.